# Typecasting a float to char

Tags: c, casting

I'm self-learning C and was experimenting with typecasting. I tried to typecast a `float` to a `char` and this was my code:

```c
# include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float a = 3.14;
  int c = 3;
  int d;
  d = (int)a*c;
  printf("I am printing a typecasted character %c", (char)d);
  return 0;
}
```

The output I got was this:

```
$ clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
$ ./main
I am printing a typecasted character $
```

The character never got printed and I don't know what went wrong. Please help.

Comment: `3 * 3` is `9` which in the ASCII alphabet is *horizontal tab*. What did you expect as output?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, I did not know what the ASCII alphabet are. I'll look that up, thanks.

Comment: Please don't paste images of output; copy-paste the text instead.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Sure, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Thanks. The one general exception would be if you're trying to show formatting, such as color, which is lost when you copy-paste. Then, it is usually best to paste both the text and a screenshot, and mention the screenshot is to see the color.

Comment: To nitpick a little: You don't cast a floating point value to `char` anywhere. In `(int)a*c`  you cast the `float` variable `a` to an `int`. The multiplication is an integer multiplication. The integer result is stored in the integer variable `d`. And you cast this integer variable to a `char`, but that will then be *promoted* to an `int` anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking, there almost exists no situation where a beginner should use a cast. Casts are very dangerous and requires in-depth knowledge about the type system and implicit conversions etc. The correct solution is most often to instead use the appropriate type to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all looks fine to me!

To better see what happened, print it as a `%i` in addition to `%c` so you can see what the decimal number value is.

([run me](https://onlinegdb.com/fN424b7xY))

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a = 3.14;
    int c = 3;
    int d;
    d = (int)a*c;
    printf("I am printing a typecasted character, \"%c\", or signed decimal "
           "number \"%i\".\n", (char)d, (char)d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> I am printing a typecasted character, "   ", or signed decimal number "9".
> ```

Looking up [decimal number 9 in an ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), I see it is "HT", `\t`, or "Horizontal Tab". So, that's what you printed. It worked perfectly.

[@Some programmer dude has a great comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344733/typecasting-a-float-to-char/70344834#comment124348828_70344733) that is worth pointing out too:

> To nitpick a little: You don't cast a floating point value to `char` anywhere. In `(int)a*c` you cast the `float` variable `a` to an `int`. The multiplication is an integer multiplication. The integer result is stored in the integer variable `d`. And you cast this integer variable to a `char`, but that will then be promoted to an `int` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Adding in some extra debug for the other variables shows why this is the case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a = 3.14;
    int c = 3;
    int d;
    d = (int)a*c;
    printf("I am printing a typecasted character %c, %f, %d, %d", (char)a, a, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `I am printing a typecasted character , 3.140000, 3, 9`

Character 9 is not in the printable ASCII range, hence nothing useful prints.

It's not clear from your question what you're expecting, but perhaps you meant %d in the format string? Or maybe you wanted to start from the printable range `(char)a + 32` or `(char)a+'0'` or something else.

Note also: many of those casts are to smaller types, so there's good chances for issues there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't expect anything particular in the output, this was my first C program with casting. But an empty space I definitely wasn't expecting. Apparently it comes from the ASCII alphabet, So I'll just look that up.

Comment: Definitely. And always remember that there's more encodings than just ASCII/latin1. That is a much broader topic, and even more exciting in C, so... yeah. Suspect you probably just want to use the right format string to print the value as a number here.